# ACF simple text field value not showing

Tags: custom-post-types, theme-development, advanced-custom-fields

I registered custom post type in functions.php like so:

```
function ourproducts_post_type() {

   /*Labels*/
  $labels = array(
    'name' => _x("Our Products", "post type general name"),
    'singular_name' => _x("Our Products", "post type singular name"),
    'menu_name' => 'Our Products',
    'add_new' => _x("Add New", "ourproducts item"),
    'add_new_item' => __("Add New Product Category"),
    'edit_item' => __("Edit Product category"),
    'new_item' => __("New Product Category"),
    'view_item' => __("View Product Category"),
    'search_items' => __("Search Product categories"),
    'not_found' =>  __("No Product categories Found"),
    'not_found_in_trash' => __("No Product Categories Found in Trash"),
    'parent_item_colon' => ''
  );

  /*Register ourproducts post type*/
  register_post_type('ourproducts' , array(
    'labels' => $labels,
    'public' => true,
    'orderby' => 'menu_order', 
    'has_archive' => false,
    'menu_icon' => 'dashicons-groups',
    'rewrite' => false,
    'supports' => array('title', 'editor', 'thumbnail', 'page-attributes'),
    'show_ui'             => true, 
    'show_in_menu'        => 'custom-options',
    //'menu_position'       => 40,

  ) );
}
add_action( 'init', 'ourproducts_post_type', 0 );
```

On front-end (on `front-page.php` template page), I tried displaying the field value outside the loop like so:

```
    <h3><?php the_field('nasi_proizvodi', $post->ID); ?></h3>
```

Also, I tried inside the loop like so:

```
<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

            <h3><?php the_field('nasi_proizvodi'); ?></h3>

<?php endwhile;  ?>
```

But nothing shows. Unless I specifically write the post id like so:

```
<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

            <h3><?php the_field('nasi_proizvodi', 4268); ?></h3>

<?php endwhile;
```

But I need them dynamically changed, not only for this particular post id.
What's funny is that I've already created several text fields on the front-page already(I am developing a theme) and I had no problem dynamically displaying those. What am I doing wrong, any suggestions, please?

Comment: please check print $post->ID; front-page.php fetch only current page id so

Comment: Hi @DharmishthaPatel, thanx for the reply. I just did - the value printed  is  4076. I do not know what this value belongs to, i don't see anything with 4076 value. I am confused.

Comment: which post id value you need? 4076 is current page id?

Comment: please print global $wp_query;
echo $wp_query->post->ID;  out  of loop  which page id has print?

Comment: As far as I can see, 82 is the front page id. I need for  4268, but not only for that one. I need them dynamically created, as i explained in my question.

Comment: yes  got it but check it form print for current page id if you have more help  for me
plese share your site details my id is os.pateldharmishtha@gmail.com

Comment: I just did print global $wp_query; echo $wp_query->post->ID; and yes, I am right - 82 is value I got.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

please check your postype and add arg

```
<?php 
$query = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'ourproducts' ) );
if ( $query->have_posts() ) :
    while ( $query->have_posts() ) : 
        $query->the_post(); 
?>
        <h3><?php echo get_field('nasi_proizvodi'); ?></h3>
<?php 
    endwhile; 
    wp_reset_postdata(); 
endif; 
?>
```